# When I copy a Google Spreadsheet (and its Apps Script project), On Edit trigger (new trigger) is missing range property

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

So I have Spreadsheet 1 and its Apps Script Project associated with it. It works. It has an On Edit [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) that references the range that is being edited (`e.range`). When logged, the event object looks something like:

```json
{
"authMode":"FULL","oldValue":"xxxxxxxxxx",
"range":{"columnEnd":2,"columnStart":2,"rowEnd":2,"rowStart":2},
"source":{},"triggerUid":"#########",
"user":{"email":"someone@somewhere.com","nickname":"smoochy"},
"value":"xxxxxxxx" 
}
```

I then made a copy of it, Spreadsheet 2. Of course it does not copy triggers so I re-created the *On Edit* [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

The problem: The event object `e` in Spreadsheet 2's trigger events do not have a `range`.

```js
const OnEdit = (e) => {  
  console.log(e)
}
```

This returns the object which is missing the `range` object:

```json
{
"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"FORMAT","source":{},"triggerUid":"#########",
"user":{"email":"someone@somewhere.com","nickname":"smoochy"}
}
```

This range property is what allows the Apps Script functions to know what row is being edited, respond only when certain columns are edited, respond by changing values in other columns in the same row, etc.

Why doesn't the copy work? And what can I do to make it work?

- I've checked that the Apps Script project *is authorized* to edit the sheet. It can read and write to the sheet. It says the correct sheet name in the project's 'overview'.
- Both appsscript.json files are identical.
- I don't see any other settings in the Project Settings for the Apps Script project that would be configured incorrectly.

The only workaround I can think of would be to create a fresh spreadsheet and paste everything into it. But that doesn't answer my question. It seems like it should work or I should be able to fix it so that it does.

Comment: In the current stage, `range` and `value` properties are not included in the event object of the installed OnChange trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) But, you say `It has an On Change trigger that references the range that is being changed (e.range). When logged, the event object looks something like:` and `range` and `value` properties are included in the event object of your question. First, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating this situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: For example, you might have installed as the OnEdit trigger?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There aren't enough details. What type of trigger has each Google Apps Script project?

Comment: My apologies. It is an On Edit trigger that I'm using. The same as on the first spreadsheet. My function was called OnChange so I mixed this up.

Comment: I've still not resolved what is causing this problem. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I then made a copy of it, Spreadsheet 2. Of course it does not copy
> triggers so I re-created the On Change trigger.

This is where you went wrong because onChange does not have a value or a range property.  You should have created an onEdit trigger.

Comment: My apologies. It is an On Edit trigger that I'm using. The same as on the first spreadsheet. My function is called OnChange so I mixed this up.